# Ho do I prevent past e char and fractional digits into input in Angular 12?

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, math, truncate

I need to prevent copy pasting "e" char and fractional digits into an input.
There is an input with trunc() started on ngModelChange. But it truncs fractional digits only for the first time, example: if testItem is 1 and one copy pasts 5.5 it shows that is 5 is entered, but if the testItem is 5 and one pasts 5.5 again it doesn't tranc it and it shows that 5.5 is entered.

There is the html:

```
        <input type="number"
               min="1"
               [(ngModel)]="testItem"
               (ngModelChange)="trunc()">
```

And the trunc() function:

```
  trunc() {
    this.testItem = Math.trunc(this.testItem);
  }
```

Ho do I prevent past e char and fractional digits into input in Angular 12?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#data="ngModel"` inside input element and access value,then use in trunc function.

input element:

```
<input type="number"
       min="1"
       #data="ngModel"
       [(ngModel)]="testItem"
       name="testItem"
       (ngModelChange)="trunc(data.value)">
```

trun func:

```
 trunc(value:string) {
    this.testItem = Math.trunc(value);
  }
```